# Select com um retorno de diversos valores de diversas colunas

Tags: select

Saudações!
Este é meu primeiro post, espero poder ser ajudado e também poder ajudar muito nessa jornada com vocês!
Então algum erro de formatação peço apenas paciência até que os padrões aqui sejam adequados!

Bom, meu primeiro problema está sendo em criar um select que retorne diversos valores que não estão em uma única coluna de uma tabela.

Preciso de fazer isso para retornar sugestões de pesquisas..
Por exemplo: Se o funcionario digitar: "tec" é carregado pelo banco de dados as possiveis frases com ele: por exemplo: teclado comum, teclado gamer, tec_fabricant, etc...

Talvez eu tenha de usar um select aninhado, mas ainda não tenho certeza:

Segue abaixo um escopo da minha necessidade:
Select *
from tabelaEspecifica
where column_name like '%tec%';

Desconsidere chave primária.

Atenciosamente.

Comment: Publique o modelo de suas tabelas, o BD que está usando (versão etc) , que ambiente usa para front-end etc , outra coisa esta pergunta é recorrente e uma simples busca vai te retornar muito material que vai te ajudar.

Comment: Não há modelo nas tabelas, são apenas duas, Cliente e Produtos, não foi feito diagrama DER, é apenas um trabalho para a Faculdade!

Comment: Neste caso um like do tipo (coluna1 like '%tec%' or coluna2 like '%tec%' ...) resolveria.

Comment: sim, mas e o select? como faria para que todos os dados fossem canalizados num único Aliase?

Comment: Não sei se entendi sua pergunta mas vamos dizer , se busca produto , fabricante , categoria etc se uma ou mais das colunas "bater" vc lista , seria isto ?

Comment: Por exemplo tenho uma tabelaA com as coluans A,B e C respectivamente, eu quero que independente da coluna, volte TODOS valores que comecem com a palavra 'tec%' com um ORDER BY DESC no final! assim a pessoa quando digita na pesquisa vem no DAtabind Todas as possíveis pesquisas daquele nome, assim se o funcionario não sabe o nome do distribuidor mas sabe o nome do produto, pode cair ele como sugestão!

Comment: a palavra chave seria "coleta e ordenação...." independente da coluna, capitura e joga na saída...é a mesma coisa que o google faz quando voce começa digitar no pesquisar dele e ele traz sugestões... a idéia é esta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, segue os passos abaixo para soluções futuras caso alguém precise:

```
SELECT colunaA as ApelidoPadrao

FROM tabelaA

Where colunaA like '%Suamensagem%'

UNION -- Esse é o cara que permite a junção

SELECT colunaB as ApelidoPadrao

FROM tabelaA

Where colunaB like '%Suamensagem%';
```

Pronto! faz com duas faz com mais:
Requer que os tipos sejam iguais.
Entretando você pode usar um `SELECT TO_CHAR(ColunaX) caso precisar de forçar um *casting*!